# Android default payment app dialog missing app icon

Tags: android, android-pay, hce

Im currently developing a NFC HCE pay app.

Its all working fine except the Android default payment app dialog.

It does show a line for my app but it does not show any icon as it shows for other apps.

Tried to find any reference at the docs but only found info about creating the service and implementing HCE payments.

At first i was thinking it will use the same icon as the app icon, especified at the app manifest, but im seeing i was wrong.

Can somebody point out where should i look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html#PaymentApps)

The image is set on "apduServiceBanner" inside the xml element "host-apdu-service"

That element should be on the apduservice xml file referenced from the element:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
           android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
```

In the App manifest inside the service declaration tag.